# Get list view item info through context menu

Tags: android

I have an list view that displays an id name description etc... i created a context menu to use on that list and i want to get the name of a specific row through the context menu. How can i do this

```
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_DATA, TAG_DATA2, TAG_QTD},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.descricao, R.id.data, R.id.data2,      R.id.qtd});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
        long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(id), 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
    case R.id.item2:

        return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom list adapter.

Then you can use an onItemClickListener to get the clicked item and so the name etc...

Here is an tutorial for a custom adapter:

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Comment: its not that i want, i want to get the R.id.name clicking on the option of the context menu of the row on the list view

Comment: No. That is exactly what you want : )

Answer (score 0):

You want to register for context menu like: `registerForContextMenu(yourListView)`.